# Automatically copy .so files from NDK library project?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

Using `Android Studio 1.2.1.1` with `Gradle 1.2.3`. I have an `NDK` library project `A` that produces a number of `.so` files in its own `libs` folder. Though, I cannot see the reference to this folder anywhere in the `build.gradle` file.

When I reference library `A` from my app `MyApp` I would expect the `.so` files to be copied to `MyApp/src/main/jniLibs`, but they aren't. Do I have to manually copy these files every time I make a change in the `A` library?

How can I automate this step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I does not know if ther is a way to have you `.so` files copied as you want whiout wirtting anything.

But you could have gradle doing it for you.
In your gradle file, add a task that copy those `.so` files where you need them to be.

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }

    //copying files
    task copyNativeLib(type: Exec, description: 'Copy native file') {
        commandLine 'cp <path_of_so_files> src/main/libs'
    }

    //add dependencies
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLib
    }
}
```

Or maybe just

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir '<path_to_your_so_files>'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I edited mine to look like below, which picks it up from where ndk-build.cmd places them.

```
sourceSets {
     main.jniLibs.srcDirs += 'libs/'
}
```

Comment: One more thing to note; the native images need to be installed. Otherwise the corresponding `.so` file will not be generated.